# define $(this) within AJAX function and append parent created in another AJAX success function

Tags: ajax

So, here's something fun!  I'm trying to run a function inside of an ajax call and populate an element within the AJAX success function with data from the other function.  Does that make sense?  Probably not, so here's my code.

**This is the end result function that relies on another function for one piece of data.**

```
function runQuery(){

var url = 'http://www.nexthometown.com/index.php?option=com_singleprop&view=raw&format=raw';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ 
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            var agentuid = value[0];
            var mlsnum = value[1];
            var address = value[5] + ' ' + value[6] + ' ' + value[7];
            var city = value[9];
            var state = value[10];
            var zip = value[11];
            $('#ohs_table').append('<tr><td>' + mlsnum + '</td><td>' + address + ' ' + city + ' ' + zip + '</td><td class="date"><div>' + ohsDate(mlsnum) + '</div></td><td><div class="media_button">QRCode</div><div class="pdf_button media_button" form="oh_usda" value="' + mlsnum + '">USDA<br/>PDF</div><div class="pdf_button media_button" form="oh_usda_null" value="' + mlsnum + '">NO USDA<br/>PDF</div></td></tr>');
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {  
        alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
    }
});


};
```

**This is the function called within the success function of the other AJAX call**

```
function ohsDate(mlsno){
var dateurl = 'http://www.nexthometown.com/index.php?option=com_singleprop&view=raw&format=raw&mlsnum='+mlsno;
$.ajax({
    url: dateurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            var date = value[0];
            var start = value[3];
            var end = value[4];
            $(this).parent('.date').append( date + ',' + start + ' - ' + end );
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('OOPS!');
    }
});
};
```

Now, the problem is I keep getting `undefined` as a result when the **end result** AJAX call in finished.  So, since I'm not getting an `'OOPS!` alert for EVERY time the dependant function is called, I can only assume it found a success, but something is undefined, which I assume to the the `$(this)` reference.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned this approach and altered the mySQL query from `WHERE` to `JOIN`.  I was attempting a band-aid fix to pull in something from another script.  It didn't work well.